# Sharepoint - How to show contents of a document on sharepoint page

Tags: image, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement wherein I need to show contents of a document on a sharepoint page. Example - Say my company wants to maintain a document wherein they continuously add some text about upcoming events/new trainings/organisational updates. Is it possible to read a word document or text file and show the contents on a sharepoint page? If yes, How to achieve this?
[P.S. - I am a beginner in sharepoint]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display word document on a page. In SharePoint Online you can use a [File viewer web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-file-viewer-web-part-e53a9602-e7b3-4fff-9126-de2f18d1900c). It will show all the contents inside the file and provide basic interactions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I did use the File Viewer, but it shows all the content at once. I am guessing there is no way I can read a few lines from the document and then display it, and then later pick next few lines from the document and show them. As and when some new lines are added to the document, I read those and show them on the page. This might not be possible in sharepoint online, right?

Comment: @IshitaDas As far as I know, there is no out-of-box solution providing such experiences. You may need to create a custom one for this.